# In PDO, I can exec() a string, but not prepare() and then execute() it

Tags: php, pdo, exec, prepare

If I `PDO::exec()` a query, it works. However, when I try to first `PDO::prepare()` *then* `PDO::execute()`, it *does not* work. Why?

For instance, this works as expected:

```
$db->exec($string);
```

This does not, though:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($string);
$stmt->execute();
```

There are no errors thrown, and `$db->errorInfo` is showing all zeroes, meaning success.

This makes absolutely ZERO sense to me.

**EDIT for *Context***:

Note, `newDB()` is just a function which initiates the DB with the settings I need here.

When I run the following, it works as expected:

```
$db = newDB();

if (!$error) {
    if (isset($id)) {
        try {
            $db->exec('UPDATE Events SET Title = "WHY" , Date = "2012-11-01 00:00:00", Place = "no", Description = "no", UDate = now() WHERE Id = "12"');
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $error = 1;
        }
    }
}

$db = null;
```

However, this does not and I do not know why:

```
$db = newDB();

if (!$error) {
    if (isset($id)) {    
        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE Events SET Title = "WHY" , Date = "2012-11-01 00:00:00", Place = "no", Description = "no", UDate = now() WHERE Id = "12"');
            $stmt->execute();
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            $error = 1;
        }
    }
}

$db = null;
```

Comment: var_dump($stmt) will show the problem :)

Comment: No problems in that, none in the error reports for PDO either.
The error reporting functions give results that mean the update should have been successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you set the exception mode ?

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Thankyou. If it were not for this, I would not have been able to get the errors.

Turns out, I was missing a comma in one of the strings.